# What cannot be done in SQL Server 2008 Web Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What can you do in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition that you cannot do in SQL Server 2008 Web Edition?

I've seen the Microsoft feature lists, but I am wondering from a very practicle standpoint where I am going to run into limitations.

Comment: It seems that downloading the trial gives you the enterprise version of SQL Server? I have a couple of questions I want to answer before I purchase web-edition - is it possible to install a trial version of web-edition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Web Edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727361/sql-server-2008-web-edition) - I know this was asked first, but that seems to have a better answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you seen this matrix as well?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

From what I can tell Web excludes a lot of the more advanced features, especially those related to development and data mining, but nothing that would stop you from using it for a non-enterprise web site's data source.  It seems to be between the Express version and Standard version.

Comment: "SQL query, edit and design tools" is not incuded in web-edition. Is this Query Analyzer? (in other words, there is no tool to run queries in web edition). So you then need Standard Edition to use queries?

Comment: There's no need to get the Standard version just to get Query Analyzer, etc. You can use the free SSMSE version: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985

Comment: Link is broken. Not a great idea to link to microsoft, they always break their links!

Answer (score 8):

One of the biggest limitations is that it can't be a publisher for SQL replication.  If you want to have multiple database and replication data between them, then you need at least one SQL server to be Standard or Enterprise to act as the publisher.

Comment: "biggest limitations" is probably over stating it.  MS's implementation of Replication leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx

Edit: Sorry, you've probably already looked at the above.