# SQL Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can somebody give me some info on SQL Server 2008 Web Edition?  Is this a new edition with 2008?  What kind of limitations does it have?  Is anybody using it successfully?  What does it provide that the Express Edition won't?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 Web Edition is a great SKU. It was specifically designed for web applications without the limitations of Express Edition. It is also WAY cheaper than Standard Edition.

Web Edition is only available through SPLA licensing, but genally costs about $25/month compared to $250/month for Standard Edition.

Web Edition does not have a database size limit, where Express Edition has a 4GB database size limit. Express Edition also only uses up to 1GB of RAM while Web Edition can use whatever the OS limit is.

While Web Edition does have to be licensed per CPU, having the reduced costs allows you to easily go to a 2 or 4 CPU box without huge costs involved. Express Edition will only utilize a single CPU if installed on multi-cpu boxes.

For a fully feature break-down check out http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx -- at the web hosting firm I work for we have found that about 90% of our non-HA customers that were using\licensing Standard Edition are able to move to Web Edition.

Microsoft has done good to the web community with this new SKU.

**Update:** With 2008 R2 Microsoft has increased the database size limit to 10GB.

Comment: "Express Edition can only be installed on single CPU boxes" -- Do you have a link for that? I thought you could install it, but it would only use 1 CPU on the box?

Comment: @Jeremy - Excellent post!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Joel. I've made the appropriate edit to reflect this.

Comment: @Jeremy H: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition has a 10 GB database size limit, not 4 GB as you say in your post (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)

Comment: @XpiritO : Yes, this changed with R2.

Comment: @JeremyH very well written. Cheers for the contrib

Comment: The feature break-down appears to have moved. Here is the new location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 10):

From [Microsoft's Web site](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx):

#### CPUs

- Web: 4 (licensed per CPU, though)
- Express: 1

#### Memory

- Web: OS Max
- Express: 1GB

#### DB Size

- Web: Unlimited
- Express: 4GB

Comment: As of SQL Server 2008 R2, Express can have a DB size of 10GB.

Comment: Memory Web: OS Max is wrong, for web edition you can only use 64GB RAM  MAX.

Answer (score 4):

you can find the complete comparison here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 R2 got more to add on Memory for WEB edition, it is 64GB.

Comment: 2008 r2 lis the latest version for sql version 2008

Answer (score 0):

Check it out youtube demonstration on youtube.com about web based sql server

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVxoYNS9J_4_A0Hy93xcBKQ